# Turkey e-visa on a one-way ticket?

Tags: turkey, e-visas

I am a Pakistani passport holder. I will be traveling to a Schengen country on a one-way ticket with Turkish Airlines. There's this requirement of an e-visa, which I am a little confused about.

**I have to prove that I hold a return ticket**, hotel reservation and at least 50$ for each day of my stay.

I don't have a return ticket, but an onward ticket to a Schengen country. So, can I apply for the e-visa? Thank you.

Comment: "I can prove that I hold a return ticket" seems to conflict with "I don't have a return ticket."

Comment: I wonder if the "I can prove ..." line is a badly marked-up quote from an application form somewhere, rather than something the OP is saying to _us_.

Comment: You don't need to prove anything, as long as you have a Schengen visa, you can apply for the Turkish e-visa online.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Whilst it's true you don't need to "prove" anything, that question is one you need to certify during the e-visa application.  Lying on a visa application is never a good idea, so I'm sure you're not suggesting they do that...

Comment: Please note that you only need an e-Visa if you plan to do some sightseeing during your layover in Turkey. If you are merely transiting (not leaving airport) you don't need any visa for Turkey.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the Turkish e-visa, the "return ticket" requirement is actually referring to the fact you have a ticket to leave Turkey.  In general this would be referred to as a "return or onward" ticket, but clearly where you are reading they have only mentioned the "return" part.

What the Turkish Government is concerned about is the fact that you have a ticket to leave their country before your visa expires (and sufficient cash to sustain yourself for that period)

The fact you don't have a return ticket from the Schengen region isn't relevant as far as Turkey is concerned.